# Promise.reject() returns its value differently from Promise.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've had a hard time figuring out how `Promise.reject()` returns its value.

```js
    const propertyData = {
      id: 1,
      propertyName: '1BR Japanese-style Private Room near Kyoto Station'
    }

    function handleClick(e) {
      getData()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.id, data.propertyName); // -> 1, '1BR Japanese-style Private Room near Kyoto Station'
            })
        .catch(err => {
         console.log(err.message); // -> 'Failed to fetch data.' if it's only 'err', it returns the object.
        })

    }

    function getData() {
      return fetchData()
        .then(result => {
          if(result.success){
            return Promise.resolve(result.propertyData);
          } else {
            return Promise.reject(result.message);
          }
        })
    }

    function fetchData() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
        setTimeout(() => {
                    if(rand >= 3 && rand <= 10){
                        resolve({ success: true, propertyData: propertyData });
                    } else {
                        reject({ success: false, message: 'Failed to fetch data.' });
                    }
            }, 1000)
      })
    }
```

First, I expected `err` in the error handling in the function `handleClick` would be the message saying `'Failed to fetch data'` because `Promise.reject()` in the function `getData()` returns `reject.message`.

However, it seems to return the object `{ success: false, message: 'Failed to fetch data.' }`.
That is why it needs to set `err.message` in the function `handleClick` in order to get the message string.
Does this prove that `Promise.reject()` always returns object even if you set the return value like `result.message`?

If so, `Promise.resolve()` looks behave differently.
It returns `result.propertyData`, so it doesn't need to set as `data.propertyData[key]` in the function `handleClick` unlike the error handling.

Do they, `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` returns its value differently? or are there something that I missed?

I hope this explains well to describe my confusion.
Thank you.

Comment: There's quite a lot of code here. Can you create a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: `fetchData` rejects, it never makes it to your `.then(result => {` in getData. If you want it to resolve with a `success: false`, use `resolve()` not `reject()`.

Comment: I can get the message even though if I use `reject()`...?

Comment: Sure you just need to catch it.

Comment: Thank you and I did catch it, but that's not what I'm stuck...maybe resolve and reject returns its value/argument differently though I can't explain.

Comment: No they work the same. https://jsfiddle.net/bekyh36L/

Answer (score 0):

```
const propertyData = {
  id: 1,
  propertyName: "1BR Japanese-style Private Room near Kyoto Station",
};

function handleClick(e) {
  fetchData()
    .then((data) => {
      // We are resolving Object with properties
      // 1. success
      // 2. propertyData (declared on line 1)
      // e.g. Accessing those
      //  - data.success OR - data.propertyData
      const { id, propertyName } = data.propertyData; // Simple destruction of data.propertyData;
      console.log(id, propertyName);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err.message); // -> 'Failed to fetch data.' if it's only 'err', it returns the object.
    });
}

function fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (rand >= 3 && rand <= 10) {
        //{ This is what will be the resolved data in .then(data => ) }
        // It can be anything you want string, Object, boolean w/e
        resolve({ success: true, propertyData });
      } else {
        //{ This is what will be the resolved value in .catch()
        // Does not necessarily have to be Object
        // But if you pass only string then in your .catch(err => )  : err here will be string
        // In your case err will be Object with props 'success' and 'message'
        // To access them u go err.message OR err.success
        reject({ success: false, message: "Failed to fetch data." });
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Comment: @Kaho does this answer your question? or I should remove it